# How Can I Attach a Box to an inside wall that will the hide internet router without damaging the wall?

Tags: storage, routers

I have a series of cables and an internet router on the floor of my apartment, like this:

[image]

I would like to attach a box to the wall that will hide all of this, and tuck the wireless router inside it. I'm not allowed to drill into the wall because this is a rented apartment.The box will have to have a small rectangular cut-out to accommodate the incoming cable from above.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

April

Comment: Think furniture (a box with legs) not something you have to somehow attach to the wall except that you can't attach it to the wall. A small cabinet or "nightstand", of the old-but not antique flavor if cost is an object, or new if not, and cut appropriate holes into the back. Even if cost is not an object, the cutting holes part should be avoided on actual antiques.

Comment: With a razor knife, it would be simple and cheap to fabricate a cardboard cover. Being lightweight, it might be tacked to the wall. Discarded boxes come in a variety of colors and patterns which may provide a range of design possibilities.

Comment: In my home, the router is located inside of my entertainment unit.  I have a rather large section of it dedicated to the router and surge protection.  Don't underestimate the heat the router will put out and once it starts overheating expect bad internet connections.  Consider a piece of furniture as mentioned by @Ecnerwal or even mounting on wall (should be mount hole on bottom of unit) with a couple of nails.  Then just tie wrap the extra cables.  This what I do in a closet where all the network cable drops are, just no cable in there yet so can't mount router in there as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should have mounting holes in the back of the router.  Simply just attach something like a [command strip](http://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-19702/3M-Office-Tape/3M-17206-Command-Picture-Hanging-Strips-Large?pricode=WY476&gadtype=pla&id=S-19702&gclid=CJjN_NDF-8ECFQmSaQod-zsAQQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) to the wall and hang the router.  We use these for the exact purpose in our personal offices at work.